# No content on getContentAsByteArray() from ContentCachingResponseWrapper in Filter if controller returning Mono<ResponseEntity<>>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-webflux, servlet-filters

As below having one servlet filter implementation and expecting response from responseWrapper but in controller 1st implementation not working and reqBody is empty string but whereas controller 2nd implementation working as it is not returning Mono type. Let me know how to get reqBody to be populated from controller response before making another request.
Note: I have to make request to another service and collate response before responding to original client.
Filter Implementation

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterchain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().contains("/quota")) {
                filterchain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
                    new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

            filterchain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);

            String reqBody = new String(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
            
            logger.info("Response string :" + reqBody);

            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(new URI("http://localhost:8084/quota"), reqBody, String.class);
            logger.info("Result" + result.getBody());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception", e);
        }
    }
```

Controller Implementation 1st

```
    @RequestMapping("/userdata")
    Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>getUserData(){
        return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>("{\"userdata\" : \"Data\"}", HttpStatus.OK));
    }
```

Controller Implementation 2nd

```
    @RequestMapping("/userdata")
    Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>getUserData(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"userdata\" : \"Data\"}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using Spring WebFlux, then this is expected: [Spring WebFlux does not expose the Servlet API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-new-framework), so Servlet Filters cannot work with the reactive programming model here.

Spring WebFlux introduced a new `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` that's comparable to Servlet Filters. I am not aware of any existing `ContentCaching` implementation for `WebFilter`.

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel can you provide me some example code for WebFilter implemntation, as i tried but request are not going through WebFilter 's filter method

Comment: Please ask a new question showing your filter implementation, your build file and Spring Boot configuration file.